# Mean curvature in asymptotic directions

Tags: differential-geometry, curvature

I'm a little confused by this question I've come across in do carmo while studying for my final.

(Sect 3.2 #7)

Show that if the mean curvature is zero at a nonplanar point, then this point has two orthogonal asymptotic directions. Can someone show me how to solve this? So obviously, $k_1+k_2=0$ but I don't know where to go from there. I'm also confused by the concept of asymptotic directions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HINT:** Write down Euler's formula. Asymptotic directions are characterized by normal curvature equal to zero.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I was able to conclude kn=k1(cos^2(x)-sin^(2)x). I'm not sure how I would go about showing that is equal to zero though.

Comment: Wait never mind! I figured it out

Comment: Yeah! Congratulations!